# "Combined Type" - Generics - something else?

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I feel like having lost my OO knowledge. Actually, the problem looks simple: I want to create a class which operates on an object which

- inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form
- implements the interface IDescribedActionsProvider

at the same time.

I could create a new Form type
public abstract class SpecialForm : Form, IDescribedActionsProvider
and require a parameter of that SpecialForm type.

But it does not work here: most of our Forms inherit from OurCompanyForm which need not implement IDescribedActionsProvider, and some of our forms do not inherit therefrom, but when they implement the interface, they should be an acceptable parameter.
It is *composition* what is required here, not *inheritance*.

Then I thought of Generics. I could define my class like

```
public class FormController<T> : IDisposable where T : Form, IDescribedActionsProvider
{
T _ControlledForm;
OtherType _OtherObject;

internal FormController(OtherType otherObject, T controlledForm)
{
    _OtherObject = otherObject;
    _ControlledForm = controlledForm;
    ....
}
```

It would work the way I intended, but it feels totally wrong:
That's not what Generics (see MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) were meant for.
And I get problems when I want to create that FormController object in a Factory (because of the OtherType which is created there) which is not generic, i.e. a function like
public FormController CreateFormcontroller(T controlledForm)
is not possible because T not defined here... And using "SpecialForm" instead of T does not work because of composition vs. inheritance.

What do you suggest? "Duck Typing" - but that's not a good OO practise either?

Edits:

The object to be passed to FormController must be of both types, because it describes to events of Form and calls methods of the interface.

Defining T in the factory method as described in Boris B.'s comment and Weyland Yutani's answer works.

But still I have doubts about the use of Generics in this context: The T controlledForm parameter is a single object, there is exactly only one instance of that "type" in the FormController class, and nowhere does the concrete type matter - that's clearly different from e.g. a List<int>. I do not "need" a FormController object, just a FormController (which happens to work on that form).

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this at all. What issue do you have with it?

Comment: "some of our forms do not inherit therefrom, but when they implement the interface, they should be an acceptable parameter"  Why not just accept a `IDescribedActionsProvider` object as the parameter?

Comment: You can define the factory method like this: `public FormController<T> CreateFormController<T>(T controlledForm) where T: Form, IDescribedActionsProvider`

Comment: Also, what is `OtherType` in practice? What purpose does it serve in `FormController` that warrants passing via constructor?

Answer (score 1):

"And I get problems when I want to create that FormController object in a Factory (because of the OtherType which is created there) which is not generic, i.e. a function like public FormController CreateFormcontroller(T controlledForm) is not possible because T not defined here..."

I might have got the wrong end of the stick but can't you just define T on the factory method?

```
class Factory
{
    public static FormController<T> CreateFormController<T>(T controlledForm) where T : Form, IDescribedActionsProvider
    {
        return new FormController<T>(new OtherType(), controlledForm);
    }
}

class FormController<T> where T : Form, IDescribedActionsProvider
{
    T _ControlledForm;
    internal FormController(OtherType otherObject, T controlledForm)
    {
        _ControlledForm = controlledForm;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, it can be done in this way. Looks like I got those many Ts wrong when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like not every Form you want to controll is of type IDescribedActionsProvider. Can't you just make two methods?:

```
abstract class FormController
{
    abstract void Handle(IDescribedActionsProvider form);
    abstract void Handle(Form form);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not correct: the FormController subscribes to Form events of controlledForm, and calls methods of IDescribedActionsProvider. Hence the object must be both.